# jQuery: slide a new item into the top of a set of items

Tags: ajax, jquery

Semi-newbie to jQuery; just can't quite get this...

I have a list of items on a page, and I want to insert a new item at the top of the list by (a) sliding the existing items down and (b) fading the new item into its position at the top of the list.  I can get the new item inserted into the list, but so far all the effects I've gotten to work are things like `$('#theList').prepend(theNewItem).hide().fadeIn(1000);`, which fades in the entire set of items, including the new one, and doesn't do anything about the sliding.

Of course (?), part of my problem is that I need to be applying the .fadeIn (and, presumably, the .slideUp) methods to the new item, not the whole list, but I can't seem to get my hands on it.  I can get the ID of the new item, but it's not showing up in the DOM after the prepend (at least, console.log('#theNewItemsID') is returning an empty list).

Any advice out there?  Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$('#theList').prepend(theNewItem).children(':first').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CrjQF/

---

**Alternative**

If the variable `theNewItem` holds a jQuery object then you can also use the [`.prependTo()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) method to skip the filtering

```
theNewItem.prependTo('#theList').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CrjQF/1/

---

**Explanation**

It happend because your initial selector is the `#theList` so the chained commands refer to that. Using the [`.children()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children) method combined with [`:first`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector we reduce the selected items to the first child of `#theList` (*the newly added*)

Comment: Very nice -- thanks!  For extra credit :), how would I get a visible slideDown of the existing items before the new item fades in?  I've tried putting a .slideDown(1000) at various points along that chain of method calls, but none of them quite seem to do it.

Comment: Excellent!  I had to tweak it a bit to work off the original .prepend() call (theNewItem is just text, not a full jQuery object), but replacing the original fadeIn call with your example's code starting at the css() call worked fine.  Thanks again!